# SAP get last program run and used parameters

Tags: abap

I am looking for a way to track a last program run and the parameters used.

E.g. for a program with a selection screen I want to check the last runtime and which parameters were entered on the selection screen.

I've checked transaction `STAD`, but it only shows last runtime and bytes transferred.

Anyone knows any way to also have the parameters or variables used for this program run?

Thank you!

Comment: Does it run in background? If yes, the parameters are stored as a program variant (except variables). If no: if it's a custom program, change it to store the last run information in a custom table; if it's a SAP standard program, change the standard to do the same.

Comment: I've found out how variants work now, how do I combine the last program run with it's variant now?

Comment: it's impossible to do without custom development, and if you wanna track just last run it is located in ST03

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether the program runs in background or not.

If yes:

- It's mandatory that a program running in a background job has a program variant assigned (unless the program has no parameters at all), and what variant a job step has used is stored in the table `TBTCP`.
- The values of the variant can be extracted by calling the function module `RS_VARIANT_CONTENTS_255` for instance. The execution date of the job is stored in tabl`TBTCO`.

If no:

- If it's a custom program, change it to store the last run information in a custom table
- If it's a SAP standard program, change the standard to do the same.